# Error using linked list remove function. after advanced for loop breaks

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to get my bet system to detect if the input numbers are duplicates. When you run the program, press 2 on the "for box" bet and follow instructions from there. The issue lies in the winlose duplicate and also for the non duplicate. I don't know how I am supposed to fix the issue.

Error stacktrace :

```
at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.checkForComodification(LinkedList.java:966)
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:888)
    at numbersgame.Test.winLoseBetDuplicate(NumbersGame.java:190)
    at numbersgame.Test.checkDuplicate(NumbersGame.java:167)
    at numbersgame.Test.WinLoseBox(NumbersGame.java:134)
    at numbersgame.Test.getValues(NumbersGame.java:117)
    at numbersgame.NumbersGame.main(NumbersGame.java:24)
C:\Users\cymmm1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Code :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package numbersgame;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author cymmm1
 */
public class NumbersGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test numbers = new Test();
        numbers.getValues();
        boolean win = numbers.win; //this checks if you won, either as a duplicate or not.
        if (win) {
            System.out.println("You won");
            switch (numbers.bet_Type) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("You waged " + numbers.bet_Amount
                            + "dollars and you will get "
                            + numbers.bet_Amount * 600 + " back.");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (numbers.dupwin) {
                        System.out.println("You waged " + numbers.bet_Amount
                                + "dollars and you will get "
                                + numbers.bet_Amount * 200 + " back.");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You waged " + numbers.bet_Amount
                                + "dollars and you will get "
                                + numbers.bet_Amount * 100 + " back.");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, you lost $" + numbers.bet_Amount + " dollars");

        }

        System.exit(0);
    }

}

class Test {

    public int bet_Type;
    public int bet_Amount;
    public int player_Number;
    public int winning_Number;
    private JOptionPane panel;
    public boolean win;
    public List<Integer> digits = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> digits2 = new LinkedList<>();

    public void getValues() {
        panel = new JOptionPane();

        this.bet_Type = (Integer.parseInt(panel.showInputDialog("What is the bet type. 1 for straight, 2 for box")));
        this.bet_Amount = (Integer.parseInt(panel.showInputDialog("How much is the bet")));
        boolean bad = true;
        while (bad) {
            this.player_Number = (Integer.parseInt(panel.showInputDialog("What is the player's Number. 3 numbers must be inputted")));

            int playerNumCopy = this.player_Number;
            while (playerNumCopy > 0) {
                digits.add(0, playerNumCopy % 10);
                playerNumCopy = playerNumCopy / 10;
            }
            int lengthOfNum = digits.size();

            if (lengthOfNum != 3) {
                bad = true;

            } else {
                bad = false;
            }
        }
        bad = true;
        while (bad) {
            this.winning_Number = (Integer.parseInt(panel.showInputDialog("What is the winning Number")));

            int winningnumbercopy = this.winning_Number;

            while (winningnumbercopy > 0) {
                digits2.add(0, winningnumbercopy % 10);
                winningnumbercopy = winningnumbercopy / 10;
            }
            int lengthOfNum = digits2.size();

            if (lengthOfNum != 3) {
                bad = true;

            } else {
                bad = false;
            }
        }
        //========END OF CHECK FOR PROPER NUMBERS=================================
        //Now to check for type of bet and se the method appropriate

        if (this.bet_Type == 1) {
            win = WinLoseStraight();

        } else {
            win = WinLoseBox();
        }

    }

    private boolean WinLoseStraight() {
        if (this.player_Number == this.winning_Number) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        // this goes back to getValues
    }

    private boolean WinLoseBox() {
        //this checks for duplicates. if it isnt a duplicate then check for a box non-dup

        boolean duplicatewin = checkDuplicate();
        if (duplicatewin) { //you either won with a duplicate number or nonduplicate. check Duplicate does to things at once
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    public boolean duplicate;
    public boolean dupwin;

    //this checks for duplicated numbers
    public boolean checkDuplicate() {
        duplicate = false;
        int[] array = new int[digits.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (int numbers : digits) {
            array[i] = numbers;
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            i++;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
                if (array[k] == array[j]) {
                    duplicate = true;
                    System.out.println(array[k] + " equals " + array[j]);
                    break; //if duplicated found, it will exit out of the for loop
                }

            }
            if (duplicate) {
                System.out.println("we found duplicate.");
                dupwin = winLoseBetDuplicate(); //if it has duplicated numbers, it will check if your numbers match up
                break;
            } else {
                dupwin = winLostBetNonDuplicate();
            }
        }

        return dupwin; //this will return if you have won the prize with a duplicated number. goes back to getValues
    }

    private boolean winLoseBetDuplicate() {
        /*how this method works is we make a linked list. 
        use a advanced for loop and when we encounter 
        a hit, we remove the number from it. 
        if there is still a number in the linkedlist of 
        player number it is a lose. we still have digits as a linked list. */
        // 
        boolean won = false;
        boolean match;
        for (int digitsnumbers : digits) {

            System.out.println("Checking the number: " + digitsnumbers);

            for (int digits2numbers : digits2) {
                if (digitsnumbers == digits2numbers) {
                    digits.remove(digits.indexOf(digitsnumbers));
                    digits2.remove(digits2.indexOf(digits2numbers));
                    System.out.println("we found a duplicated numer match. Removing from choosing. ");
                    System.out.println(digits);
                    System.out.println(digits2);
                    match = true;
                } else {
                    match = false;
                }

            }

        }
        if (digits.size() > 0) {
            won = false;
        } else {
            won = true;
        }

        return won;
    }

    private boolean winLostBetNonDuplicate() {
        boolean won;
        for (int digitsnumbers : digits) {
            for (int digits2numbers : digits2) {
                if (digitsnumbers == digits2numbers) {
                    digits2.remove(digits.indexOf(digits2numbers));
                    digits.remove(digits.indexOf(digitsnumbers));
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        if (digits.size() > 0) {
            won = false;
        } else {
            won = true;
        }
        return won;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you need to use Iterators instead.  There's an example around 2/3 of the way down [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html)

Comment: Thank you. Although I only have about 4 hours of experience in programming in java... so if you can guide me as I'm going through it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I don't really have the time, but there are plenty of other online Java tutorials that mention iterators.  I'm sure you'll manage to work it out, now that you know what it is that you need.

Comment: yeah I looked at the error, issues with removing a element that is being iterated through. although I don't see how to implement this so yes I will look for other tutorials that can help but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Present [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code.

Comment: for (Iterator<Integer> iter = digits.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

            System.out.println("Checking the number: " + iter);

            for (Iterator<Integer> iter2 = digits2.iterator(); iter2.hasNext();) {

Comment: @YoungMillie it is complete, minimal and verifyable. just remove package

Comment: I don't think so `Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well that's the thing. I need all that code. the classes are integrated within each. feel free to tell me which parts are not needed.

Comment: ok. I fixed it. thanks so much for that @DavidWallace I will edit my code and reupload it at the top so you can enjoy. Have a fantabulous day.

Comment: You're welcome.  Don't reupload it at the top.  Better if you just leave the question as it is.

Comment: ok. but it worked. the whole programs runs beautifully. So I learned something today... lists are great but can be weird when you remove elements from them.